# Need to reassemble tcp packets with netty

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, netty

currently I am working with an inhouse protocol where I send a request to our hardware and receive the answer with netty. In the message which I receive are several bytes which tell me how many bytes the answer will contain. 
In my channelRead method I wait until the readable bytes of the recieved message are equal or greater than the expected bytes to make sure I get all data.

```
if (((ByteBuf) msg).readableBytes() >= dataSize) {
        //do something with the bytes
        ctx.close();
        ((ByteBuf) msg).release();
}
```

This works fine if I receive exactly one tcp package from the hardware. Sometimes the hardware splits the TCP frame into several packages and my channelRead waits for ever.

Is there a simple way in netty to reassemble these packets in the channelRead method?

Comment: What do you do if `readableBytes()` is less than `dataSize`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extend ByteToMessageDecoder. This will handle all the buffering for you. Check the javadocs for more details and an example.